# boost-build (aka bjam) with Intel archiver command instead of ar

Tags: c++, bjam, boost-build, icc

When I use boost-build with the Intel compiler, using the built-in "intel" tool, it uses `icpc` when compiling source into object files, but uses `ar` to make `.a` static libraries. Normally this is perfectly fine because Intel's own archiver `xiar` is mostly a wrapper for `ar`.

However, I'm trying to use Intel's "inter-procedural optimization" (`-ipo`) option when I build some (but not all) of my libraries/modules within a large application. I want it to optimize within the library/module, but not between libraries/modules. For that to work, I have to use `xiar` or `xild -lib` when making the `.a` files because `ar` doesn't understand the `.o` files that are created by `icpc -ipo`. It thinks it succeeds, but the `.a` it makes will fail in the linking stage.

How can I change what command boost-build will use to create archives away from the default `ar` to `xiar`?

I've tried throwing in `<linker>` (which I see the msvc built-in tool supports) to the `using intel` statement in my user-config.jam, but it seems to have been ignored. And I don't know that would affect the archiver choice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had to hack into boost-build's internals to make this work. If you need this feature, you can hack it too!

In `/usr/share/boost-build/tools/intel-linux.jam` or perhaps `/usr/share/boost-build/src/tools/intel-linux.jam` (which one exists might depend on you boost-build version), add the following to the end of the file:

```
actions piecemeal archive
{
    "xiar" $(AROPTIONS) rc "$(<)" "$(>)"
    "ranlib" "$(<)"
}
```

This seems to override the default `archive` (and `piecemeal`?) actions that are defined in `gcc.jam`. Here I explicitly use `xiar` instead of `ar`, and the rest is just copied verbatim.

If you aren't using Linux, you could probably move the same logic into `intel-win.jam`.

I believe that boost-build is flawed in this  assumption to use `ar` even with the intel compiler, so this might become a bug fix request on boost-build soon. I'm not confident I have the best solution, but it's better than nothing.

Even better would be to add a `<archiver>` feature. Such a thing is mentioned in google results, but definitely doesn't exist in boost-build (between 2011 and 2014 versions). Obviously boost-build is capable of implementing such things. But I lack the skills in the very confusing jam language to make that happen. Please share if you do have such skills.